# Why does the ItoProcess command give me the error, "is not a random process recognized by the system"?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have a 5-dimensional diffusion process I want to simulate $\omega,\theta,y,v,z)$.  It somewhat degenerate in that all terms don't involve Brownian motion, but that shouldn't be a problem in the simulation. I get the error, "is not a random process recognized by the system"

```
     h  =  7.587*10^(-10);
    (*h  =  7.587^(-8);*)
    k3 = 3.85*10^(-15);
    k1 = 7.91*10^(-15);
    m = 1.26*10^(-23);
    Iz = 6.7806*10^(-41);
    Rd = 4.47*10^(-32);
     kT = 4.085*10^(-21);
    e = 10^7;
    q = 1.602*10^(-19);
    g = q*e;
    domega = Sqrt[2 Rd kT];
    
    fmass[x_] := ( k1/m) + ((k3 - k1)/m)*Cos[x]
    
    Subscript[\[Omega], 0] = 1.;
    Subscript[\[Theta], 0] = Pi/4;
    Subscript[v, 0] = 0.;
    Subscript[y, 0] = 0.;
    Subscript[z, 0] = 1.;
    tt = 7.*10^(-7);
    
    ClearAll[proc, \[Omega], \[Theta], y, v, z]
    
    proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]\[Omega][
           t] == -(Rd/Iz) \[Omega][
            t] \[DifferentialD]t + (domega/Iz) \[DifferentialD]w1[
             t], \[DifferentialD]\[Theta][t] == \[Omega][
           t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]y[t] == 
         fmass[\[Theta][t]] \[DifferentialD]t,
        \[DifferentialD]v[t] == 
         Sqrt[2 kT*fmass[\[Theta][t]]]*Exp[y[t]]*\[DifferentialD]w2[t],
        \[DifferentialD]z[t] == Exp[y[t]]*\[DifferentialD]t}, {\[Omega][
         t], \[Theta][t], y[t], v[t], 
        z[t]}, {{\[Omega], \[Theta], y, v, z}, {Subscript[\[Omega], 0], 
         Subscript[\[Theta], 0], Subscript[y, 0], Subscript[v, 0], 
         Subscript[z, 0]}}, 
       t, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
        w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}];
    
    process = RandomFunction[proc, {0., tt, h}]
```

Solve::ivar: (1+0.5 Cos[[Theta][t]]^2) [DifferentialD]t is not a valid variable.

RandomFunction::unsproc: The specification ItoProcess[<<1>>] is not a random process recognized by the system.

Comment: I just ran your code in a fresh kernel and got no error. I get a TemporalData object from t=0 to 7e^-7 with 1 path and 924 data points. If you get a different result, the error message gives you a clue. Click on the red dots to the left and pull up a stack trace. That may help you isolate the problem. Solve may be called internally and is being passed invalid data. The only connection I see between a Cos and your equations is via the exponentials; i.e. if the argument became complex somehow. But as I said, it works fine for me. I ran it a few more times and still see no problem.

Comment: Thanks jdp. I will run it again, but I ran it several times before requesting help.

Comment: @complex, have you tried restarting Mathematica (quit the kernel with `Quit`)? Also, in such cases, it helps if you let us know which version of Mathematica you are using.